# Can not connect to mongodb container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I can not connect to mongodb container created with docker-compose

the mongodb configuration (in docker-compose.yml) is as follow:

```
mongodata:
  image: mongo:3.0.4
  volumes:
    - /data/db
  command: --break-mongo

mongo:
  image: mongo:3.0.4
  volumes_from:
    - mongodata
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  command: --smallfiles --rest --auth
```

When I run:

> docker-compose ps mongo

I got:

```
      Name                    Command               State            Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
followit_mongo_1   /entrypoint.sh --smallfile ...   Up      0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp
```

and I cannot connect with mongo client, the bellow command

> docker-compose run mongo mongo

fails and this is the error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.4
connecting to: test
2015-11-10T17:10:32.735+0000 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-11-10T17:10:32.741+0000 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try publishing 27017 container's port to host with -p option

docker-compose run -p 27017:27017 mongo mongo

I can access mongo from host that way.

Comment: I get always the same error: couldn't connect to server

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I enabled access control which require user authentication before creating users. So I have to remove the --auth flag from mongo command, create administrator user:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

then restart mongodb server with access control :)

For further information about access control, see http://bit.ly/1QgVlW2